# How would you implement generics like Vector.<T>?

Tags: actionscript-3, generics

So, ActionScript 3 has generics with the Vector class (Vector.).  I have not seen any other class that uses generics like this.

If you were to implement Vector. yourself, how would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are after generics then you are best off to look at [Haxe](http://haxe.org/). It is very similar to ActionScript 3 and compiles to a swc or swf.

Answer (score 1):

Coming back to haxe post above... you can create generics in haxe and then compile the code to as3. Not tried it recently to see how it is handled, but.. http://haxe.org/doc/flash/as3gen

Answer (score 0):

Well you could make a class that takes a type T as a parameter, something like this
    Foo( type:* )

And then in all the methods from which you can add items to the Vector class, I wouls raise an excpetion if the type of the object passed to the method doesn't match the type I defined when I instanciated my vector class.

That being said, you probably wouldn't get very good performance from a class like that, since everytime you handle an object you need to check it's real type at runtime, where as in C++ template classes are created a compile time, so no runtime type checking needs to be done.

Comment: No, I was really looking to understand how to implement it exactly... with the generics syntax that Vector uses and compile-time checking... they did it once... how did they do it?

Comment: Generics don't exist in AS3, you can't create template classes or anything like that. The closest thing to generics, is the built in Vector.<T> type.

Comment: But Vector does it... is it a special compiler one-off?

Comment: Yeah but the Vector class is built into the AS3 language, so you could say it's a compiler one-off yes. We can also hope that Generics will be implemented into AS3 one day!

Answer (score 0):

AS3 does not support generic class declaration. There's a good discussion [here](http://alecmce.com/as3/why-we-need-generics-in-as3)

Comment: Could an object of type `Object` be used as a generic?

Comment: Not that I know of. Besides, using Object skips the whole compile time check process, which isn't that useful in that case.