# Declare generic class (like Vector) in Actionscript3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

As you all know, Vector support type checking by added Type parameter.

```
var v:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
```

I wonder if I am able to create a custom class that have Type parameter, something like this

```
var myClassInstance: MyClassDefinition.<String>;
```

Thank you.

Harry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would you implement generics like Vector.<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071536/how-would-you-implement-generics-like-vector-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActionScript doesn’t (yet) support generics. `Vector` is a special case with support hard-coded into the compiler.

See also: [Why doesn't ActionScript have “generics”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848365/why-doesnt-actionscript-have-generics)